# How to remove shipping row from checkout review order table in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to remove the **Shipping** **row** in **Checkout** in the **review order table** in **Woocommerce-Wordpress**.

I tried using simple CSS but nothing happened.
Code I was using:

```
tr.woocommerce-shipping-totals shipping { 
    display: none !important; 
}
```

[image: Preview Row]

Comment: Hi @Goodman, we're going to need a little more information to help you. Where are you adding this CSS? Can you share the HTML code of the shipping row?

Comment: Also note that it's better to embed images directly in your question description instead of linking to them.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
tr.shipping { 
    display: none !important; 
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Path: woocommerce/cart/cart-shipping.php

and

> wp_kses_post( $package_name )

Comment: A little context and additional information would improve this answer.